# K-centers clustering using R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I can't find a simple library function for k-centers clustering using R, whereas I could for k-means (`kmeans()`) and hierarchical clustering (`hclust()`).

Is there a library function for simple greedy k-centers clustering using R as depicted in [this  post](http://proteneer.com/blog/?p=207)

If not - as I am new to R - how would one go about implementing it (I understand the logic - just not how to actually write it in R code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `kmeans` with `method = "centers"`.

If this is not what you are looking for, then CRAN has a cluster Task View with dozens of packages at http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html.

Answer (score 1):

From what is described in this blog post, this seems similar to one of the many seeding strategies used for k-means. I wouldn't really call it a clustering method yet, but a pre-clustering or something like that.

Maybe you should lookt at the `flexclust` package of R, I believe it has some k-means variations and initializations, and maybe it has this variant as one initialization option. Or it might be on http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html

Note that always choosing the object that is furthest away is prone to choose outliers as cluster centers! Have a look at e.g. k-means++ which is based on a similar idea, but somewhat more clever (plus, it better supports randomization, so you can try multiple different initializations). Or you could choose the object that is closest to the `(2k-1)/(2k)` quantile, which probably is a better guess for a good cluster center.